# Fedora 17 application dowload

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, fedora-17

I'm normally a mac user when it comes to desktop and have some experience with Ubuntu desktop as well.

For my spare pc I decided to try out beautiful Fedora and I'm done with install and updates.

I was wondering though, is there an app for downloading software like on Ubuntu or Mac? (like apt-get but in visual form to browse and see).

Also, how can I get drivers (proprietary and not)

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably looking for [yum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified).

Comment: I use yum with centos server. Is there a desktop version of it too?

Answer (score 1):

System → Administration → Add/Remove Software

drivers usually should be packages as well, unless the vendor packaged in a different form, in which case you just need to follow their instructions.